# Target select when dropdown open rather than focused (CSS or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## What I have:

A bordered select element. When the dropdown is open (i.e. focused), the bottom border is deliberately removed to achieve this look:

[image]

...rather than this look:

[image]

The difference being the two being one 1px border instead of two 1px borders between the select element and dropdown.

## What I need:

I need to prevent the bottom border from being removed when the select element is tabbed into (i.e. focused but dropdown not open).

Currently, my result undesirably removes the bottom border when tabbing:

[image]

## My code:

```css
label,
select {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

select {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #666;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #111;
  border: 1px solid #0073aa;
  background-color: rgba(0, 115, 170, 0.2);
  border-bottom: none;
}

select option {
  color: #111;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<label>Fruit:</label>
<select>
  <option value="" selected></option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="plum">Plum</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
</select>
```

## Note:

I don't want to have to replace the select element (e.g. jQuery UI).
I'm willing to use jQuery to target or style the select element.

Comment: Bear in mind that some browsers apply their own styles to selects which you cannot control. E.g. your careful styling will not work on a Mac. If you need to fully customise the look and feel, you should look into replacement solutions which simulate the functionality with standard DOM elements.

Comment: @DarthJDG Noted, thanks. It's for a locally hosted site that will only ever be accessed by Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the styles in your `select:focus` selector to `select:active` as well, but introduce the behavior of the bottom border to the `:active` and `:focus` pseudo-selectors separately:

```
select:active, select:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #111;
  border: 1px solid #0073aa;
  background-color: rgba(0, 115, 170, 0.2);
}

select:active {
  border-bottom: none;
}

select:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0073aa;
}
```

This way when you tab over or click on the dropdown, the styles are applied, sans the bottom border style. Since clicking makes the element active but tabbing does not, we need to make sure the bottom border shows up when we simply have focus on the `select`.

Comment: Your solution doesn't appear to remove the bottom border when the dropdown is open as required: https://jsfiddle.net/Clarus_Dignus/s72fzrv6/

Comment: I provided the incorrect fiddle. Here's the correct fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Clarus_Dignus/s72fzrv6/2/